# bad request socket python

Tags: python, sockets, bad-request

I'm  using socket to build a simple "web browser" but I'm getting stuck at the start, whit a bad request result, here is my code:

```
import socket
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
URI = 'data.pr4e.org'
mysocket.connect((URI, 80))
cmd = "GET http://{0}/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n".format(URI).encode()
mysocket.send(cmd)  # send a request

while True:
    data = mysocket.recv(512)  # recieve 512 bites at time
    # if there is no more information to recive, then, close the loop
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
    pass

mysocket.close()  # close connection
```

here is the output

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 15 Feb 2021 14:36:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 308
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</
h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at do1.dr-chuck.com Port 80</address>
```

what I'm doing wrong? also, I tryed replacing data.pr4e.org by facebook.com and youtube.com and I get this output:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Location: https://facebook.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
X-FB-Debug: LPmWQm0VVptVpi8QX8/SxymrJg9ZoL/mL+W+G4pZA4HGj5WI5YIG1s8sgqwp6TIleGvUg3U1eDNEhGoCsaJG5g==
Date: Mon, 15 Feb 2021 14:52:43 GMT
Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

thank you

Comment: The HTTP command shouldn't include the protocol or the hostname - it should just be `"GET romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"`.  (Using just `\n` for the line endings will often work, but isn't technically valid.)

Comment: More precisely, it needs to specify an __absolute__ path, i.e. `GET /romeo.txt ...`. Also, you need a Host header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is just that you used `\n` when the server expected `\r\n` for end of line.

Anyway, as you directly connect to the HTTP host, you should not put the full URI in the request line. This would be better on a HTTP 1.0 conformance point:

```
cmd = "GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".encode()
```

But if the server could accept more that one virtual server, you should pass the name in a Host header:

```
cmd = "GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {}\r\n\r\n".format(URI).encode()
```